# How to hide address bar and tab bar in Firefox?

Tags: firefox

How to hide the address bar and tab bar of Firefox 51?

I want to create a floating window with just the title bar and content but no other bars of any kind visible.

- no need for disabling them completely just hide them
- pressing F11 doesn't do the trick (no floating window)
- solutions without add-ons preferred

Comment: Why not just use a proper “web to desktop application” tool? Something like Electron or whatever.

Comment: If you right-click on the menu or an existing icon (but not in the text input area of the address or search bar, you can uncheck all the tool-bars. If you click **Open Menu** (three horizontal bars) and then **+ Customise** at the bottom, you can add and remove specific tool icons. You may want to use a separate profile for this, so you can easily switch back to "normal" browsing.

Comment: For OP information, I have added [this new answer in the linked question](https://superuser.com/a/1269912/109256), which does not require to use any add-ons.