# Firefox Quantum (>=57) How to toggle all toolbars? (with a keyboard shortcut, like F11 but in a window, not fullscreen)

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, browser-addons, firefox-extensions, firefox-57

F11/Fullscreen is sometimes impractical*. I just want to toggle the toolbars.
In older Firefox versions this was possible with the addon "Dorando keyconfig":
 ***1. specify a script:***

```
var s = document.getElementById('status-bar');
s.hidden = !s.hidden;
var b = document.getElementById('PersonalToolbar');
b.collapsed = !b.collapsed;
var nb = document.getElementById('nav-bar');
nb.collapsed =!nb.collapsed
var tb = document.getElementById('TabsToolbar');
tb.collapsed =!tb.collapsed
```

***2. map it to a keyboard shortcut via the Dorando addon-interface***

This addon is not availabe anymore in Firefox 57 and above.

**Question**: (How) can I toggle every toolbar via the Webextension or an addon in Firefox version >= 57? (preferebly with a hotkey)

notes: I found the addon https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/custom-style-script/ where you can implement custom JavaScript and CSS code, but I don't know (did not find out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions) how to address the toolbars.

**imagine you want to watch a tutorial in seperate window, but with the maximum video size. Or read an article with the max screenrealestate in a splitted i3 container on linux...*

---

**update 02.2019**
after waiting a long time and searching, ClairelyClairs [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1277988/452309) seams to be the only viable method.
but it has it's downsides. So here are some tips to it:

- create a new firefox profile where the userChrome.css is placed in the profiles "chrome" dir.
- start your normal firefox-profile and then additionally start this second profile, e.g. `firefox -p notoolbars` for the purpose of watching webinars or such.
- another tip: beside userChrome.css use userContent.css to disable banners and things (see [mozillaZine article](http://kb.mozillazine.org/index.php?title=UserContent.css&printable=yes) and [this](https://github.com/stylish-userstyles/stylish/wiki/Valid-@-moz-document-rules)

Comment: Doesn't solve your problem, but some relevant info: No Dorando keyconfig in FF57 [according to author](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dorando-keyconfig/reviews/924874/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't give you a keyboard shortcut, but you can use the :hover pseudoclass to allow auto-showing the nav box (the toolbars at the top of the browser window) when you hover at the top of the window.

Put this in your userChrome.css:

```
@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul");

#navigator-toolbox {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 3px;
    margin-bottom: -3px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition-property: height;
    transition-delay: 1s;
    transition-duration: 2s;
}

#navigator-toolbox:hover {
    height: 62px;
    transition-property: height;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}
```

You will also want to tick the "show title bar" box under Customize.

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this key sequence: <kbd>Alt-v, t, b</kbd>

Comment: thats a nice and easy idea, but this just disables the toolbar or alternatively the menubar - not all toolbars (navigation, tab, bookmark)

Comment: Ah, the Question is about toggling them all, not just one.  Apologies.  I'll remove this answer shortly.

Comment: no need to remove :)

Answer (score 1):

Building on ClairelyClaire.msft's answer (which is great!), here are a few improvements (add to your userChrome.css):

- Keep toolbars visible when they have focus (so they don't disappear while you're typing a URL).
- Hide toolbars completely but keep receiving mouse events, so that the browser's title bar is no longer needed (no need to enable "show title bar" in Customize).
- No need to specify the toolbars' height manually in the code (which is also more robust in case it changes).

```
#navigator-toolbox {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    max-height: 7px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 2s ease 1s, opacity 3s step-end;
}

#navigator-toolbox:hover,#navigator-toolbox:focus-within {
    max-height: 100px;  /* must be somewhat larger than actual bar height */
    opacity: 1;
    overflow: inherit;
    transition: max-height 0.3s ease 0s, opacity 0s step-end;
}
```

Comment: Ought this still work in firefox 79? on macOS? Somehow I'm not getting the results ‍♂️

Comment: `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets` needs to be set in `about:config` 

Comment: Yep you still need to follow the official guide on changing `userChrome.css`, it changes from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

As all the answers here depend on the Firefox `.css` files, it should be noted
that starting in Firefox 69, both `userChrome.css` and `userContent.css` are disabled
by default "to improve performance".

To re-enable them do the following:

- Enter `about:config` in the Firefox address bar
- If asked, click "Show all"
- Enter in the search bar: `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets`
- Toggle the preference. *True* means Firefox supports the CSS files,
  *False* that it ignores them.

---

Note that there are more answers to this same problem in the post
[Firefox hide everything except content area of the browser](https://superuser.com/questions/977912/firefox-hide-everything-except-content-area-of-the-browser).